# How to do split payments while taking an application fee AND not being the merchant of record using Stripe Connect?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

So I'm trying to charge a buyer $100.

Proceeds will go to Seller A and Seller B, 50/50, after Stripe fees + my application fees (5%).

I don't want to be the merchant of record, so I have to use a direct charge, not destination charge.

**This is very important -- I don't want to be liable for anything, I'm just the guy who facilitated the transaction.**

I tried creating a direct charge on behalf of Seller A for $100, while setting my app fee as $5 (i.e. 5%):

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(amount = 10000, currency = 'usd', stripe_account = {{ SELLER_A_ACCOUNT_ID }}, application_fee_amount = 500)
```

So far so good.

Once the payment was made, I tried to transfer $50 from Seller A's connected account to Seller B's connect account by creating a Transfer object:

```
stripe.Transfer.create(amount = 5000, currency='usd', destination='{{ SELLER_B_ACCOUNT_ID }}', stripe_account = '{{ SELLER_A_ACCOUNT_ID }}')
```

Doesn't work!

It gave me error:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_BUamIs2khdEsbf: Cannot create transfers between connected accounts. If you're trying to debit a Connected account then you can learn more here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits. If you require further assistance, please contact us via https://support.stripe.com/contact.
```

Fine fine fine.

So I decided to take a larger application fee ($55), and then transfer $50 from my platform account to Seller B (using a webhook listening to the `payment_intent.succeeded` event), instead of transferring $50 from Seller A to Seller B.

Now it says my account has insufficient funds, even though the application fee of $55 has entered my platform account:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_IYLEYMmcN5E7lF: You have insufficient available funds in your Stripe account. Try adding funds directly to your available balance by creating Charges using the 4000000000000077 test card. See: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#available-balance
```

What gives?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after being on live chat with Stripe support.

The key is to use the `on_behalf_of` parameter when creating a `PaymentIntent` object:

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(amount = 10000, currency = 'usd', on_behalf_of = '{{ SELLER_A_ACCOUNT_ID }}')
```

This creates a charge on the platform itself, but with Seller A as the Business of Record. This is distinct from creating a `PaymentIntent` object using the `stripe_account` parameter.

Next, I create separate transfers to Seller A and Seller B (amounts are just illustrative):

```
stripe.Transfer.create(amount = 5000, currency = 'usd', destination = '{{ SELLER_A_ACCOUNT_ID }}', source_transaction = '{{ LATEST_CHARGE_ID_OF_PAYMENTINTENT }}')
```

```
stripe.Transfer.create(amount = 5000, currency = 'usd', destination = '{{ SELLER_B_ACCOUNT_ID }}', source_transaction = '{{ LATEST_CHARGE_ID_OF_PAYMENTINTENT }}')
```

And voila, it works instantly.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Transfer, if you don't specify the `source_transaction`, it'll always try to use the funds from your available balance and if the payment funds is not yet available then you will possibly run into the problem of insufficient funds (if you have insufficient funds in your [available balance](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_object#balance_object-available))

Unfortunately, since you're using Direct Charges, the Charge doesn't exist on your account and you can't pass in a Charge id into the `source_transaction`. You'll need to keep track of your [available balance](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_object#balance_object-available) before making a transfer.

To check if the funds from a payment is still pending / available, you can look for the Charge's [balance_transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-balance_transaction), and then check [available_on](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-available_on). You can get these data in a single API call by expanding the relevant parameters : https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects

Side note about using `source_transaction` : if you pass in a Charge id into `source_transaction` and if the payment is still pending, then the transfer will pull the funds from the pending balance. If the payment is already available, then the transfer will pull the funds from the available balance.

Comment: It would not allow me to specify a `source_transaction` (it says `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_ghZlivT65XpJAL: No such charge: 'ch_3Ny1u6F18w81dttL1kZ9aBzJ'`). Which is expected because the original PaymentIntent was created on behalf of Seller A, not on behalf of the platform (me). So the Charge doesn't even exist in my account, but only in Seller A's account.

Comment: ah, yeah, totally missed out on that. Editing my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got this from another question... could this help?

Instead of using Destination Charges via the transfer_data parameter (which is meant for a one-to-one seller/buyer relationship) you want to use Separate Charges & Transfers (meant for a many-to-one seller/buyer relationship) to create multiple transfers -- one to the seller and one to the affiliate. When you do so, you want to use the source_transaction parameter (docs) when creating your transfer to tie the Transfers to the original Charge and allow you to create these transfers instantly. The funds still won't be available until the normal delay, but this will solve your "insufficient funds" issue.

Comment: No, that doesn't help (I know it works), for the simple reason that it makes me the merchant of record for that transaction. Which is what I'm not looking for. Thanks though.